# Trouble using integrate.nquad: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float

Tags: python, integrate

I have a problem using the function `integrate.nquad.`

> I get this error: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of
>   type 'float'"

I understand that I have a string somewhere, but I can´t find it exactly

If someone would please help me with this I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
def f(D,S):
        Ka = 0.08
        C = 500
        R = 0.05
    return np.exp(-Ka*C*((R-S)*np.cos(D) *(np.sin(D))**2))
Io = 3.58*10**16
R = 0.05
I = (Io/(R*np.pi)) * integrate.nquad(f,[[0, R],[0, np.pi]])
```

Comment: There's no string issue. A tuple issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
def f(D,S):
    Ka = 0.08
    C = 500
    R = 0.05
    return np.exp(-Ka*C*((R-S)*np.cos(D) *(np.sin(D))**2))
Io = 3.58*10**16
R = 0.05
I = (Io/(R*np.pi)) * integrate.nquad(f,[[0, R],[0, np.pi]])[0]
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html), `nquad` returns 2 (or 3, if the right parameter is set) items: the result (integrated value), the maximum of the estimates of the absolute error in the various integration results, and optionally a dict with additional information.

You're attempting to multiple a 2-tuple returned by `nquad` by `(Io/(R*np.pi))`: that's causing your error.

Take the first element of the returned tuple (note the `[0]` as the last bit of code above) and you'll have what you want.